# Set up g++ on OS X

Tags: macos, gcc, osx-mavericks

I just updated to OS X Mavericks and it seems it messed up my whole compiler setup. Not only do I have to reinstall a JDK in order to use a Java compiler, I get the following error when I'm trying to compile C/C++ using GCC/G++:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.7.2/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/cwchar:46:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
```

Not sure what to think other than upgrading messed it up. My question is: how do I set up g++ to compile on OS X? If it's already set up, what is the problem here?

If I can provide more information, please let me know.

Note: I've installed gcc 4.7 using homebrew, but it doesn't seem to work. When I use `g++-4.7 code.cpp` specifically, I get the same error.

Comment: afaik osx gets set up when xcode gets installed with the `command line tools`

Comment: Originally, yes. I tried to set it up on the latest version back on ML and had it working. I can't remember how I got it set up, though, and I feel like there shouldn't have been a major change to that in upgrading...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing the **Command Line Tools (OS X Mavericks) for Xcode - Late October 2013** solved it for me. Here is the link:

[OSX: Xcode Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-#)

The often mentioned `xcode-select --install` command kept saying it cannot find the requested software.

To clarify: You need to already have gcc-4.7 installed using Homebrew. The update to the latest version of CMD Tools only fixes compatibility issues caused by upgrading from  Mountain Lion to Mavericks.

Comment: Do you know if this will allow for C++11 support? I have the Command Line Tools installed, but I think I did this early this year or possibly late last year.

Comment: Using `g++-4.7 --std=c++11` gives C++11 support. I have been using the Mac OS 10.8 Command Line Tools while using Mountain Lion (most likely the one you have downloaded). Upon upgrading to Mavericks I received your aforementioned error msg and installed the appropriate Command Line Tools for Mavericks. From then on all has been running smoothly.

Comment: I'm confused; you say you solved it by installing the Xcode command line tools and yet you aren't using them if you are using `g++-4.7`.  When you have Xcode 5 command line tools installed then `g++` is an alias for `clang++` as there is no GCC support in Xcode 5.

Comment: Apologies, I should have clarified: This 'fix' is based on a gcc-4.7 installation using Homebrew.