# Details in setting up custom debugger in eclipse cdt (OS X 10.9)

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb, osx-mavericks

The reason I need to set up a custom debugger is that the debugger simply doesn't work in eclipse: Error while launching command: gdb --version. I have installed the command line tool (late Oct version), and the solution here [Set up g++ on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557614/set-up-g-on-os-x)
doesn't work either.

I am trying trojanfoe's solution here:
[debugger for c++ using eclipse on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536142/debugger-for-c-using-eclipse-on-mac/21962724#21962724)

but I am stuck:
(1) The gcc, gdb install finishes with an instruction to: 
You will need to make sure /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist has the '-p' option ...

(for the ProgramArguments key)

But I can't edit this file, can't change its mode, how do I make sure it has -p option? (it only has -s in my mac)

(2) How do I set up the gdb debugger in eclipse c++ IDE? I know trojanfoe's solution has pointed to some websites, but it looks very confusing to me, so would appreciate some more details. Thank you.

Comment: Instructions for how to edit com.apple.taskgated.plist here: [stackoverflow.com: How to get gdb installed with homebrew code signed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20048346/2554472).

Comment: AFAIK this is bug in eclipse. Can you run "gdb --version" from command line? If you can, try cleaning up your path (this helps on Windows).

Comment: Thank you both. Indeed I found the way to edit the taskgated.plist file as Mark Plotnick mentioned. I couldn't run gdb --version from command line as dbrank0 suggested. The final way I figured out is that on Mac, gdb is called ggdb, therefore once I point eclipse cdt's debugger to /opt/local/bin/ggdb, everything then works. Thank you all!